# Difference between IPA ɚ, ɹ, and ɝ

Tags: pronunciation, vowels, rhoticity, ipa

Wanting to be more Californian and trying to correct my accent, I'm looking at [the sound for mother](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/research/gsound/Eng/Database/Phonetics/Englishes/ByWord/Word_056_mother.htm), in the North America column. What is the difference between IPA symbols for ɚ, ɹ, and ɝ. (ɝ is not on the page but the difference between ɚ and ɝ is what I was looking for in the first place.) I cannot really hear a difference between Standard Canadian and Standard American, for example.

Comment: You will not, in general, find any difference in rhotics between standard American and Canadian dialects. However, America does have several arrhotic accents.  The word *mother* will not sound different in most cases, but if you hit an arrhotic accent it may.

Comment: I'm American, and in my dialect, and I believe in most American dialects, the only difference between ɚ and ɝ is that ɚ is not stressed. Using two different IPA symbols for stressed and unstressed versions of the same vowel is probably an abuse of IPA notation, but there's enough tradition behind it that it isn't going to change.

Comment: @PeterShor Since as I understand it IPA is used to describe all phoenomes irregardless of languages, I would assume if there are two symbols for it, it should sound different. So, you're saying that when it comes to English, it's an misuse of at least one of the IPA symbols, and when used to describe another language these two symbols in fact sounds different (and the difference is other than stressing)?

Comment: @huggie it's just how they do it. Sometimes it's possible to have two symbols for the same sound. Just take /t/ and /d/ and add the voiced and devoiced diacritic respectively, for instance. We tend to in English write most unstressed vowels as schwa, even though they are not  all identical. Just oddities of loose transcription. You'll find similar idiosyncrasies in the transcriptions of other languages, especially in broad or phonemic transcriptions. The reasons will vary, but ultimately, tradition is tradition, for better or for worse

Comment: I am happy to know the difference between ɝ and ɚ as being stressed and unstressed. As far as trying to hear the real difference goes, that's no concern to me if that's the only difference between them. I mean I can hear it. So that's all good. The ɚ and ɹ though, I cannot hear a difference between the dialects. I suppose there is a difference. Or is there not a difference?

Answer (score 6):

An `/ɝ/` is just the stressed version of an `/ɚ/`.   For example, *murder* has both of them in it, being normally written as `/ˈmɝdɚ/`.  Both of those are “*r*-colored” vowels.  However, some transcribers prefer to represent that as `/ˈmɜɹdəɹ/` instead, writing a consonant instead of little rhotic hook.  Those represent the same pronunciation.

Your *mother* is therefore going to be either your `/ˈmʌðɚ/` or your `/ˈmʌðəɹ/`.  You need to understand though that `/ɚ/` and `/əɹ/` are just two ways of writing the same thing — at least in words like *murder* and *mother*.  When you can get into words like *murdering* or *mothering*, then you cannot use the *r*-colored version for the one before the *-ing*, since it now has a vowel after it and so much be written as a consonant.

There are advantages and disadvantages to doing it one way or the other.  Using a consonant instead of a diacritic can be easier to understand, since you don’t have to think about whether it has a consonant following it  and so counts as a rhotacized vowel, or whether it has a vowel following it and so counts as a consonant.

- *mirth:*          `/ˈmɝθ/`      or  `/ˈmɜɹθ/`
- *mother:*       `/ˈmʌðɚ/`      or  `/ˈmʌðəɹ/`
- *mothering:* `/ˈmʌðəɹɪŋ/`
- *murder:*       `/ˈmɝdɚ/`      or  `/ˈmɜɹdəɹ/`
- *murdered:*   `/ˈmɝdɚd/`    or  `/ˈmɜɹdəɹd/`
- *murderous:* `/ˈmɝdəɹəs/` or  `/ˈmɜɹdəɹəs/`
- *murderer:*    `/ˈmɝdɚɚ/`    or  `/ˈmɜɹdəɹəɹ/`

Another issue is that  IPA doesn’t have special precomposed characters for other rhotacized vowels, so you have to build the others yourself, which means they don’t look like the precomposed ones:

- *Mordor:*               `/ˈmo˞do˞/` or  `/ˈmoɹdoɹ/`
- *corner:*                 `/ˈko˞nɚ/`   or  `/ˈkoɹnəɹ/`
- *harder:*                `/ˈhɑ˞dɚ/`    or  `/ˈhɑɹdəɹ/`
- *radar:*                 `/ˈɹeɪdɑ˞/`   or  `/ˈɹeɪdɑɹ/`
- *carport:*              `/ˈkɑ˞po˞t/` or  `/ˈkɑɹpoɹt/`
- *rarer:*                  `/ˈɹeɪɹɚ/`    or  `/ˈɹeɪɹəɹ/`
- *creature:*             `/ˈkɹitʃɚ/`  or  `/ˈkɹitʃəɹ/`
- *entrepreneur:*     `/ˌɔntɹəpɹəˈnɚ/` or `/ˌɔntɹəpɹəˈnɜɹ/`
- *entrepreneurial:* `/ˌɔntɹəpɹəˈnʊɹiəl/`

If you are doing phonemic transcriptions, you might consider just sticking with `/r/` and not worrying about all the various phonetic realizations possible for 
it, including `[ɝ]`, `[ɚ]`, `[ɹ]`, `[ɻʷ]`, and all the rest.

As for trying to identify difference between the several Canadian accents and the many American ones, when it comes to your *r*’s, this mostly depends on whether you are comparing rhotic dialects with non-rhotic ones.  Note also that the standard versions of both sets are rhotic.  That means your *mother* is still going to be the same wherever you are, and that you don’t need to worry about it. The *mother* of Vancouver is the same as the one from San José.

You haven’t said whether your first language is some variety of English, or whether it is something else.  If it is something else, especially one without the sorts of rhotics that occur in North  America, then simply mastering those alone will be much harder, and much more important, than trying to tease out one or another difference between this or that American or Canadian accent.

Comment: As an aside, I say /ˈmʌðɚɹɪŋ/ and not /ˈmʌðəɹɪŋ/. However, no dictionaries use this notation, presumably because this is not a phonetic distinction that could possibly discriminate between two words in English. (Well … maybe not; *shut a ring* and *shuttering* would be a minimal pair here for me.) But this might be relevant since the OP is asking about how to correct his pronunciation.

Comment: "Another issue is that IPA doesn’t have special precomposed characters for other rhotacized vowels, so you have to build the others yourself".  Technically, IPA has it, but Unicode included it as a modifier letter rather than a combining diacritic.  So a font designer would need to create set of "ligatures" that mimic a combining diacritic, but I think the the rhotic hook would work like the ogonek in that although being a diacritic, it really would do better being custom tailored to each base letter. Since most font designers aren't linguists, they don't recognize it as a combiner.

Comment: My first real exposure to English is around 12 and it lasts for 10 years. My native language is Taiwanese and the Taiwan's variant of Mandarin Chinese. I learn a bit IPA through a linguistics course a long time ago and it's really rusty. To my ear, American English all uses the rhotic version so that's what I'll be concerned with. When I made recordings of myself I can tell my pronunciation is off but I need to repeat a few times to be able to hear what and where things go wrong. (Wonder why it sounds perfect when sounds transmit through my skull.) But I don't think I can catch them all.

Comment: So I would want to see if it's easy to train a ear to hear the difference. I think I get your `/ɜɹ/` and `/əɹ/` being the alternative to `/ɝ/`and `/ɚ/`. A few questions. (1) since /ɜ/ is a different sound from /ə/ I don't see why `/ɜɹ/, /ɝ/` and `/əɹ/, /ɚ/` should sound the same. I would say `/əɹ/` to me seems more correct. (2) I don't get "since it now has a vowel after it and so much be written as a consonant." By much you mean "must"? And why?

Comment: (3) If mother of Vancouver is the same as the one from San José, then why the IPA symbols are different for the standard Canadian and American? I still don't get the difference between `/ðɹ/` vs `/ðɚ/`. (interestingly all the local American variant do not use the Standard American dialect. *shrug*)

Comment: In terms of phonemic transcriptions of English, there is no difference between /ˈmʌðɚ/, /ˈmʌðɹ/, and /ˈmʌðəɹ/. I believe the first two technically mean slightly different things in IPA, but not all Americans pronounce the 'r' in *mother* the same way, so the first may be valid for some dialects and the second for others. For the third, some transcription systems use /əɹ/ as a shorthand for /ɚ/ because that lets you use one fewer IPA character, and doesn't result in any confusion since the difference between /əɹ/ and /ɚɹ/ don't distinguish between any words.

Comment: @huggie I write it as a consonant when there are vowels to either side so that I can show they are separate syllables, similar to how the /w/ and /j/ glides can separate syllables.

Comment: @PeterShor "but not all Americans pronounce the 'r' in mother the same way". That is why I would like to see if I could hear the difference among the dialects and why I'm posting the original questions. If it's valid for some dialects but not for others, then to me the difference in pronunciations is worth attending to, and so are the different IPA transcriptions. So if a page is made dedicated to all sorts of dialects, I hope the differences in IPA transcriptions are meant to describe the subtle differences in sounds.

Comment: The two contrasting ways of pronouncing 'r' in American English are the [alveolar approximant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alveolar_approximant) (along with several closely related phonemes) and the ['bunched r'](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2010/02/bunchedmolar-r.html). There is apparently quite a bit of [controversy](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2010/02/bunchedmolar-r.html) about whether these two sounds are distinguishable or not. Some Americans use one method, some the other, and some both. I don't know whether there's any research about how this varies with dialect,  though.

Comment: Looking at the webpage you've linked to, it looks like it was produced by (1) recording a bunch of speakers with various accents and (2) transcribing the results to IPA. It is certainly not true that most Canadians say /ˈmʌðɚ/ and most Americans say /ˈmʌðɹ/; and it may just be that the Canadian they found happened to say /ˈmʌðɚ/ and the American they found said /ˈmʌðɹ/. That is, this particular difference is the speaker rather than the dialect.  I can't hear the difference, but that might be because all these r's are allophones for Americans (like /l/ and /r/ are allophones for Japanese).

Comment: I'm also not sure of the accuracy of the IPA transcriptions. The Boston accent is non-rhotic, so it's supposed to be /ˈmʌðə/. But it certainly sounds like the speaker is saying /ˈmʌðɹ/ to me. Note that for some words, like *north*, the speaker of the Boston accent certainly leaves out the /r/. And another transcription mistake: the North Carolina AAVE speaker leaves out the /r/ in *north*, but it's in the transcription.