# Difference between /əʳ/ and /ɚ/

Tags: orthography, phonetics, ipa

Consider the word 'future.' Cambridge Dictionary shows the transcriptions /ˈfjuːtʃəʳ/ and /ˈfjuːtʃɚ/. Are they different?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhoticity_in_English

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between IPA ɚ, ɹ, and ɝ](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192979/difference-between-ipa-%c9%9a-%c9%b9-and-%c9%9d)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One is the Standard British English pronunciation, and the other is the General American English pronunciation.

In the British pronunciation, you don't pronounce the /r/ after /ə/ unless the next word starts with a vowel. (The superscript /r/ is saying add an /r/ after it if the next word starts with a vowel. Compare the words *store* /stɔːʳ/ and *star* /stɑːʳ/.)

In American pronunciation, you combine the vowel /ə/ and the /r/ into a single r-colored vowel represented by /ɚ/.

They're the same phoneme; it's just pronounced differently in British and American English.

Comment: Isn't that recorded somewhere for everyone to access and learn (known formerly as GR)?

Comment: Some of the accents in the UK are still rhotic.... see the Wikipedia link in my comment to OP.

Comment: @Spencer: And some accents in the US are non-rhotic. And there are different pronunciations of /r/ in the U.S, even among the rhotic speakers. I should probably say *Standard British Pronunciation* and *General American Pronunciation*, to make it clearer.

Comment: And Ireland is mostly rhotic where Australia is mostly non-rhotic ([but apparently changing](https://www.quora.com/Are-Australian-accents-becoming-rhotic-voicing-the-letter-r)). I'd have just presented it as rhotic vs. nonrhotic and then parenthetically mentioned the general tendencies in British versus American English, but what the heck, it's your answer.

Comment: @Spencer: I don't think it's just rhotic vs. non-rhotic. Scotland is rhotic, but supposedly pronounces *future* as /ˈfjuːtʃər/ rather than /ˈˈfjuːtʃɚ/. [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_English).

Comment: @Spencer That was just one user's view, which was actually about r-insertion which is a normal feature of non-rhotic accents. Another user answered that Australian accents are becoming _less_ rhotic.